# Writing scripts for PostgreSQL to update database?

Tags: postgresql, versioning

I need to write an update script that will check to see if certain tables, indexes, etc. exist in the database, and if not, create them.  I've been unable to figure out how to do these checks, as I keep getting `Syntax Error at IF` messages when I type them into a query window in PgAdmin.

Do I have to do something like write a stored procedure in the public schema that does these updates using Pl/pgSQL and execute it to make the updates?  Hopefully, I can just write a script that I can run without creating extra database objects to get the job done.

Comment: What kind of updates and what are you trying to check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on PostgreSQL 9.1, you can use `CREATE TABLE ... IF NOT EXISTS`

On 9.0 you can wrap your `IF` condition code into a `DO` block: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html

For anything before that, you will have to write a function to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into [pg_tables](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/view-pg-tables.html)?

```
select * from pg_tables;
```

This will return (among other things) the schemas and tables that exist in the database. Without knowing more of what you're looking for, this seems like a reasonable place to start.

Comment: Actually, yes, I have looked into pg_tables.  I'm using queries against this table (and others) to determine which changes need to be made to the database schema.  The problem was I didn't know how to get my logic to work, as Postgres doesn't support IF statements unless they're in some sort of function.  The DO block statement lets me build those IF statements and execute them.  That's what I was looking for.